# Create an array based on a range object

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I was wondering whether it is possible to load an Excel range object into an array. Suppose we have an Excel sheet with the following values in A5 to A7, 1 to 3 (i.e. one in A5, 2 in A7 and 3 in A7). I use the following code:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Test As Range
    Set Test = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:A7")

    Dim arrayMe As Variant
    arrayMe = Test

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        MsgBox (arrayMe(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

If I run the code, I will get index out of bound exception. More specifically,
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because a vertical array when assigning the value directly, even if one column, is a 2 dimensional array.

[image]

So you need to add the second dimension when referring to the array:

```
MsgBox arrayMe(i,1)
```

Comment: On this site: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/, I see the example with arr(1) = 22. Could you explain this?

Comment: In that example the user is looping through the range and populating a 1D array.  when assigning the values directly from a range it becomes a 2D array.  You don't have to believe me, put a break in the code after loading the array and expand the array in the locals window, you will see that it has a second dimension.  There are many tricks to turning a 2D array with one column into a 1D array.

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation Scott! I really appreciate that you explain it so clearly. I never knew the default behaviour of VBA was that it would automatically create a 2D array for a Range.